# How to apply parallel Pool.map to a nested list

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a nested list (basically a matrix) of arguments that I want to pass to a time-consuming function. I would like to parallelise the code using `multiprocess.Pool`. If I had a list of parameter I would simply call `Pool.map` on that list.

But how can I use `Pool.map` on the matrix so that the results are still in a 2D matrix format?

Say I have a function `f(x)` and a list

```
l = [[1, 2, ..., n], [n + 1, ..., 2n], [(m-1)*n, ..., n*m]
```

How do I obtain the list

```
[[f(1), f(2), ..., f(n)], [f(n + 1), ..., f(2*n)], [f((m-1)*n), ..., f(n*m)]
```

by using a process pool to parallelize the evaluation of f, which is a time-consuming function?

Comment: post an example of the how do you want to process the data please

Comment: @DanielSanchez I edited my question. I know that a possible solution would be to flatten out the list `l`, map `f` to it and then reshape the output appropriately, but I wonder if there is a cleaner and more Pythonic method.

Comment: check out the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a simple example, just call `map` over the matrix applying `pool.map`:

```
import multiprocessing


def add(x):
    return x + 10


if __name__ == "__main__":

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool() # build the process pool
    l = [range(10) for _ in xrange(10)] # we build an example list
    res = map(lambda x: pool.map(add, x), l) # we apply the pool.map with the map to the list
    multiprocessing.freeze_support() # this line is needed on windows only
    print res
```

This is the printed res:

```
>>>[[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Comment: OK thanks! So this evaluates in parallel each row of the matrix. This can however be less efficient than parallelizing the evaluation of the whole matrix, as maybe the number of available cores is not a divisor of the length of the rows and so some cores might be idle while they wait for the rest of the processes of the row to be completed.

Comment: @Pincopallino, you must make your pool to spawn as many process as processor you have in the computer. On process peer operation is not the way to approach this.

Comment: Probably I didn't express myself well enough. I was saying that if I have say 6 processes and one row of the matrix has 10 elements, after the first six elements of the row are evaluated, there will be two cores idle, waiting for the remaining 4 elements in the row to be evaluated, while the first two element of the next row could be evaluated in the meantime. Or does this approach queue all the elements of the matrix together?

Comment: @Pincopallino, no, you are right, otherwise you need to flat the list or build your own process pool that knows how to handle that specific improvement :)